# Message: Undefined property: EE::$template

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I try to use `template` lib in my project. I do

```
$this->EE->load->library('template'); 
$this->EE->template->parse_globals($template_query->row('template_data'));
```

but I get fatal error

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: EE::$template

Filename: member_sync/mod.member_sync.php

Line Number: 158

Fatal error: Call to a member function parse_globals() on a non-object in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Domains/henigdiamondscouk/public-html/henig-cp/expressionengine/third_party/member_sync/mod.member_sync.php on line 158
```

what I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->EE->template->parse_globals($template_query->row('template_data'));
```

should be:

```
$this->EE->TMPL->parse_globals($template_query->row('template_data'));
```

Comment: thank you, I know that, but I suppose EE->template should work as well, as manual says :)

Comment: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#calling-the-template-class The class' name is TMPL so you need to access it using TMPL. You're assuming the class is named `template` which it is not.